# Script Type Module not loading in IOS - Using BrowserStack to test

Tags: javascript, web-component

I am using web components to build a web application. Currently its not using any server side code. Trying to load in a script module.

```
<script type="module">
    console.log("module");
</script>
```

This will load fine in a desktop browser. I get what I expect in the Console. For Mobile IOS this script is not outputting into the console

I am trying to import my custom elements using a script module import and this is working everywhere but the iphone.

EDIT: I know that web components don't have much to do with the supplied code. Just background on why I am doing. This is the most simple example that I can not get to work

EDIT2: Seems that it run type `nomodule`.

So question now becomes:Whats the best way to run a Module in these browsers?

Figured out that Safari doesnt like variable being declared in Classes.

```
class TestElement {
    testVar = "test";
}
```

into this

```
class TestElement {
  _constuctor() {
    this.testVar = "test;
  }
}
```

Comment: what version of iOS do you use?

Comment: I have tried on Browser Stack - IOS 12.3 - Iphone X as well as on

Browser Stack 
OS: iOS, v9
Browser: Safari

@Supersharp